# User Journey Flow: Whole Process or Singular Process

Tags: design, users, task-flow, user-journey

So I'm working on this product at work, I'm designing a user journey however I am a little stuck between choosing to design the whole process from signup till the end and following a specific scenario.

My reason for being stuck is because the product can have various scenarios from the start, maybe you want to track your weight or steps or learn from an article viewing feature we have.

What should I do?

Comment: For clarity; do you mean with "signup" creating an account or logging in?

Comment: This is one of those questions that is best answered by trying something and see if it gets too complicated or whether you will have the time and resource to deliver something that is actionable and can be added to later on when you get more time to do research...

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, the 'whole process from signup till the end' consists of multiple individual scenarios. The signup flow is one scenario. After that, users have to complete a set of tasks (which all are individual scenarios) until he reaches the end.

Start by defining what users can do with your product and work on specific scenarios from there on. Also be sure when users reach 'the end' of your product and what you want them to do from there.

Answer (score 0):

Am guessing your product would be based on some sort of key insight or use-case. 
I would suggest launching the product in a beta just thinking thru the basic use-case cleanly, while the other flows can be clunky. But you've got to have  your measurement systems ready as well as a sounding board to discuss the data with (who helps you overcome your confirmation bias).
Then you can get an idea of what users want from your product, and then optimize the design for the winning flow / use-case!

Answer (score 0):

For the completeness and efficiency I'll define the whole journey.The journey is supposed to cover the various scenarios to ensure the product can help user to finish task.

I'll suggest that you can use various color line to present specific scenario, for example red line starts with signup and green line starts with article. I imaged the journey will look like a metro system map.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, You should align journey with goals. If not aligned, your flow will go in all directions and mess it up.

Answer (score 0):

The entire journey is comprised of several possible scenarios, each with a specific goal. So, even if you draw out the entire journey, you are still drawing out scenarios. You still have to make some choices about what scenarios to include. The difference would simply be that you are creating some kind of narrative thread to bring those scenarios together—a persona or a life event, or whatever makes sense for your particular product.